# Using multiple PayloadResponses with one PayloadRoot

Tags: spring

I have a spring web service that receives one `@RequestPayload` but needs to be mapped to multiple `@ResponsePayload`. From what I can see in any examples, the `@PayLoadRoot` localpart matches the `@RequestPayload` so I can't duplicate this in the Endpoint. In Spring, how can use the same payload but map to multiple responses? Thanks

Comment: `@ResponsePayload` only indicates that the result should be treated as the payload of the response. It doesn't matter what you return. Just make the return type `Object` (or a common super class) and return what you need.

Comment: The ResponsePayload is the method. The RequestPayload is the Parameter passed to the method and the PayloadRoot matches the RequestPayload. The problem I have is that the Parameter I am passing to each method is the same (i.e. the message passed in the SOAP request) but I need it to be used in multiple methods. This Spring web service has been converted from a CXF & Javax web service where the WSDL generated resulted in a <end:method></end:method> allowing me to dictate which service the endpoint hit per request. How do I do this in pure Spring?

Comment: From what I can see, WS-Addressing could solve my problem but it would require different URI's per request. My request URI has to be the same for all requests so the message itself needs to specify which method to be mapped to

Comment: I strongly suggest a read of the Sprnig WS doc as what you mention isnt how it is meant in Spring WS. `@ResponsePayload` has nothing to do with the method but the result of the method.  Spring WS by default uses the type of payload to determine what needs to be called (i.e. the document driven part, a single document triggers a single action) it doesn't know anything else. If you want something else to happen you have to either use a SOAP Action or ws addressing or something along that lines.